# Pandas Future Warning message when attempting to limit a certain amount of rows in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to limit a certain amount of rows in a dataframe based on when a column hits the first value that is equals to null. But each time, the dataframe has "B" in the columns. There is a Warning Message:

> WARNING:py.warning...: FutureWarning: In a future version, the Index constructor will not infer numeric dtypes when passed object-dtype sequences (matching Series behavior)
> return Index(sequences[0], name=names)

My code looks something like this:

```
 if "A" in list_column_names:
            # Retrieve a list of values based on A Column when it is equal to null
            list_of_null_section = df.loc[df['A'].isna()].index.tolist()
            # Get the minimum index value from the list of null section
            min_null_section = min(list_of_null_section )
            # Limit up to the last row where section = null value
            final_df = final_df.iloc[:min_null_section]
 elif "B" in list_column_names:
            # Retrieve a list of values based on B Column when it is equal to null
            list_of_null_section = df.loc[df['B'].isna()].index.tolist()
            # Get the minimum index value from the list of null section
            min_null_section = min(list_of_null_section )
            # Limit up to the last row where section = null value
            final_df = final_df.iloc[:min_null_section]
```

The if statement for A works fine, but when it gets to B. I get the warning. The logic is pretty much the same, but I don't understand why B would get the warning.

I have verified in my code that the if statement is where the root of the warning is coming from. I checked on google, and didn't see anything similar to what I was doing. The closest warning would be this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45858.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# Stores the index of all rows with missing values
list_of_null_section = []

# Get the index name, to be added back to `final_df`
index_name = df.index.name or 'index'

# Resetting the index of `df`
df = df.reset_index()

# Avoiding code duplication
for col in df.columns.intersection(['A', 'B']):
    list_of_null_section.extend(df.loc[df[col].isna()].index.tolist())

final_df = df.copy()

# This `if` condition is to avoid trying to filter the dataframe, in case
# no missing value is found, or in case columns 'A' or 'B' are not present in
# the dataframe
if list_of_null_section:
    final_df = final_df.iloc[:min(list_of_null_section)]

# Setting the original index back to final_df
final_df = final_df.set_index(index_name)

# If your original dataframe had no name for the index, then we'll remove the
# name 'index' from it.
if index_name == 'index':
    final_df.index.name = None
```

### Testing

To test the above code, I've created a dummy dataframe, with three columns, and an non-integer index:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 5],
    'B': [5, '6', np.nan, np.nan, '9'],
    'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

list_of_null_section = []
index_name = df.index.name or 'index'

df = df.reset_index()

for col in df.columns.intersection(['A', 'B']):
    list_of_null_section.extend(df.loc[df[col].isna()].index.tolist())

final_df = df.copy()

if list_of_null_section:
    final_df = final_df.iloc[:min(list_of_null_section)]

final_df = final_df.set_index(index_name)

if index_name == 'index':
    final_df.index.name = None
```

The above code returns the following `final_df`:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 5 | a |